# Is there always a linear iterative alternative to a recursive iterative process?

Tags: algorithms

This may very well be a silly question but I'm trying to cement my understanding of the material in the SICP (http://goo.gl/QXrbtV). My intuition (common sense) says yes, but wondering from a theoretical point of view if this always holds true.

Comment: is a turing machine iterative?

Comment: It is interesting that this has been marked as off topic. I would've thought, but please correct me if I'm wrong that linear recursion and iteration are rudimentary features of computation, no?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple and elegant answer for you. @k20 hinted at it in his comment.

Yes, there always is. You can simply emulate the call stack that would be created if you ran a recursive process.